# How can I generate metadata output with clang similar to that of gcc-xml?

Tags: c++, gcc, metadata, clang

I found that GCCXML is not being maintained anymore (I think the last version is from 2009 from their CVS repository). People usually suggest to check out clang, but I couldn't find a comprehensive documentation that described how to generate a similar output. Not necessarily XML, but the same information in a parsable (documented, if binary or obscure) format. If there is a way to get the same information from a recent gcc version, that is also fine.

<sup>This is for a hobby project for dynamic invocation of C++ code. I know about similar projects (pygccxml, xrtti, openc++), but the point is to make it, for fun.</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There used to be a way to print an xml dump with Clang but it was more or less supported and has been removed. There are developers options to get a dump at various stages, but the format is for human consumption, and unstable.

The recommendation for Clang users has always been code integration:

- Either directly using Clang from C++, and for example use a `RecursiveASTVisitor` implementation
- Or use `libclang` from C or C++.

Unlike gcc, clang is conceived as a set of a libraries *to be reused*, so it does not make much sense to try and write a parser for some clang output: it is just much more error-prone than just consuming the information right at the source.

Comment: Of note: `libclang` is generally meant for 3rd party tools to be built upon and as such a great deal of attention is paid to binary compatibility between releases.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll go with this one.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Clang based CastXML to generate XML file.

https://github.com/CastXML/CastXML

Answer (score 0):

You could code a GCC plugin, or better yet, a [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension, to do that. You'll need a GCC 4.6 or later version (4.7 is coming out soon).

However, extending GCC, either thru a plugin coded in C or better yet with an extension coded in MELT (a domain specific language suited to extend GCC) takes some time, because you need to understand and handle most of main GCC internal representations (Gimple and Tree-s).

If you want to use MELT, I'll be delighted to help you.

Comment: How dependent is melt on a particular version? If I develop a MELT extension, can I be reasonably sure that it will work with a later version of the compiler?

Comment: It is as dependent as plugins are... Even if you code a plugin in C for GCC 4.6, you have no guarantee that it will work for GCC 4.7.... (You'll surely need to recompile it, and you might need to rework it). In that aspect, MELT is not better than plugins in C. GCC does not currently promise a stable API for plugins, so MELT can't promise it neither! In practice, I try to make MELT releases working with latest GCC release (4.6 today) and with the future one (4.7 today).